how to make it so that when a user sends a certain message during an active state, the bot outputs the text in AIOGRAM3
if Quest_5.quest_II == list_5[0] and message.text == 'lucky':
await message.answer('Correct!\nWant to continue?', reply_markup=Keyboard.stop_button_1)
if message.text != 'удачливый' and message.text != 'Other option' and message.text != 'Stop':
await message.answer('Uncorrect', reply_markup=Keyboard.stop_button_1)
This is what i was trying to do and nothing happend
